# Postgres server performance falls off a cliff after a certain number of records

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, cursor

I am using a cursor to retrieve records from a large postgres table. (400 million records, using child tables to partition the data.) My cursor is defined as:

```
select * from parent_table order by indexed_column
```

Using both JDBC and psql, performance is consistent for the first few hundred thousand retrievals. After that it falls off a cliff and never recovers. On the server CPU, memory, and disk activity are fairly even; i.e. nothing system based stands out as an obvious culprit. I was initially suspecting this might be a network issue, but I've reproduced this from different networks.

Here's psql:

```
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 13995.910 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 13852.955 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14037.631 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 13818.516 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 13952.260 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14257.836 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14115.941 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14375.485 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14898.741 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 14086.004 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 59841.556 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 198176.211 ms
db@dbdev> fetch 100000 from all_persons;
Time: 162593.582 ms
```

And here's JDBC (retrieving 10000 at a time; the number at the left is the count of the filtered set of records which are inserted back):

```
...
536040 retrieve in 405; filtering in 28; insert in 1734
544739 retrieve in 413; filtering in 27; insert in 1713
553574 retrieve in 382; filtering in 27; insert in 1761
563167 retrieve in 348; filtering in 28; insert in 2019
572723 retrieve in 363; filtering in 27; insert in 2048
581736 retrieve in 363; filtering in 28; insert in 1784
591131 retrieve in 480; filtering in 28; insert in 1869
600260 retrieve in 377; filtering in 27; insert in 1831
608234 retrieve in 24074; filtering in 27; insert in 1566
616212 retrieve in 23711; filtering in 27; insert in 1649
624449 retrieve in 25913; filtering in 27; insert in 1587
632528 retrieve in 29981; filtering in 27; insert in 1527
641334 retrieve in 23231; filtering in 27; insert in 1728
650427 retrieve in 27883; filtering in 27; insert in 1996
659516 retrieve in 34422; filtering in 27; insert in 1774
```

While the psql performance appears to be getting worse, the JDBC performance stays roughly consistent at least through a million records (bouncing between approx 34k and 17k milliseconds).

What explains the sudden drop in performance?

#### (edit) WORKING SOLUTION:

I solved this by dropping the batch size (retrieve/insert) to 5000, and running the cursor against each child table in sequence (rather than the parent table). I also removed the order by from the cursor, as that seemed to help, even though the order by was against an ordered index.

My guess is that this gives postgres the best chance to load a full partition at once.

Comment: have you run an "analyze" on the database?  It may be that it is easy for postgres to find the first items, but then has to run all over memory to get the last ones

Comment: You are much better off trying to express this as a single query, rather than fetching rows, filtering, and inserting them back.  Is this possible?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to apply the BuzHash algorithm (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/AveryefficientjavahashalgorithmbasedontheBuzHashalgoritm.htm) to generate a hash. Definitely feasible in SQL but it'll take me some time.

Comment: @qwerty9967 I just ran analyze; good idea, and I should have thought of that. Unfortunately I still see the cliff effect (and, this time, much earlier - approx 200000).

Comment: This BuzHash algorithm does not look very different from good old Zobrist hashing. Has somebody been reinventing the wheel, or am I missing something?

Comment: @wildplasser here's an article on hashing which describes both approaches: http://e-university.wisdomjobs.com/data-structures/chapter-1181-290/hashes.html

Comment: It is a nice link, but it does not answer my question. It still appears, somebody has been re-inventing Zobrist hashing. (the java 16bit character thing does not change much IMHO)

Answer (score 3):

My guess on the performance is the following.

You have an index on "indexed_column" . . . this is just guess (based on the name).  Postgres is using the indexed column for the sort.  Furthermore, the table was created in increments, so the first million rows or so of the table are all on a contiguous set of pages in the database.

If this is true, then the following is happening.  The sort is happily going to the index and finding the records it needs.  It loads the page into memory, if the page is not already there.  In almost all cases -- for the first million or so rows -- the pages are there, and the results are returned quickly.

After that, though, something bad happens.  The index specifies a row, and the page with the row is probably not in memory.  So, it has to go fetch the page, often replacing (flushing) one already in the cache.  That is, each row reference basically requires a disk I/O.

By the way, this situation can occur on any table, even one that is not created in a particular fashion.  However, getting a million rows is a lot of rows to get out before filling the cache, unless they are ordered.

Now, how can you fix the problem.  The best way is to put the filtering logic into the database, where it belongs.  After all, returning hundreds of millions of rows to an application is not a good use of a database.  That is the first place I would look.

You could do something drastic and see if dropping the index and doing the actual sort for the order by is faster.  If the above description is correct, then it is faster -- with the caveat that you will wait a long time for the first row.

The one thing you can do is to recreate the table, sorting the data by the indexed column, and then re-indexing it (that is, turning the column into a clustered index).  This will improve things in the future, but that process will take a bit of time.

Two other possible things to try.  Assuming you need only a subset of columns in the table, create a temporary table, and pull the data from there.  With 400 million records, this will take a while, but, if the needed fields are small relative to the original records, it will improve performance.

Second, if you don't need the data in a particular order, then just pull the records without the order by.  This should replace the index scan with a full table scan, which eliminates page thrashing.

Comment: Yep on both assumptions (index & incremental build.) I can move the filtering logic to the DB, but this job may finish before I do so and test it thoroughly. (I'm creating new tables based on a source table, adding a hash derived using BuzHash.) Dropping the table isn't going to fly, although that would be great (for other reasons too); there are other users/jobs using it at the moment. I guess I'll start working on a buzhash function :/

Answer (score 0):

I second Gordon's points and will add my own experiences with cache misses.  Basically what happens is that at a certain point data in the cache ends up expiring, and suddenly you have a significant amount of disk I/O.

I did a bulk payment stored procedure for a customer, and for small payment batches it worked perfectly but for large ones, it would choke.  After some testing we noticed the following:

when up to a few hundred invoices were paid, it would perform very well.  With 200-500 invoices paid for a vendor it would start to slow down, and with 1000 or more invoices paid for a vendor, it would seem to hang.  I talked to a PostgreSQL guru who looked over the code and immediately suggested a cache miss.  We rewrote the code with this in mind and performance became tolerable.

What I would recommend doing in your case is to figure out exactly what needs to be retrieved from the application perspective and writing your query to do as much as possible within that query.  I don't know exactly what you are doing so I don't know if sorting is enough.  However I have seen HAVING clauses solve performance issues like these so it is worth looking not only at sorting but also aggregation and also whether the initial query in any way combines reads with writes (such as through a function call in the field list).  This is always a performance killer and will make cache misses exceptionally painful (that was in fact a major issue in my learning experience mentioned above).

In general my experience with PostgreSQL is that your performance is always best when you get exactly the information the application needs, and as much of the set processing logic is pushed into the db.